# Clean long string from spaces and tab in python

Tags: python, string, format

supposing to have a long string to create and this string is within a method of a class, what is the best way to write the code?

```
def printString():

    mystring = '''title\n
    {{\\usepackage}}\n
    text continues {param}
    '''.format(param='myParameter')

    return mystring
```

this method is well formatted but the final string has unwanted spaces:

```
a = printString()
print(a)
title

    {\usepackage}

    text continues myParameter
```

while this method gives the corrected results but the code can become messy if the string(s) is long:

```
def printString():

    mystring = '''title\n
{{\\usepackage}}\n
text continues {param}
    '''.format(param='myParameter')

    return mystring

a = printString()
print(a)

title

{\usepackage}

text continues myParameter
```

some hints to have a good code quality and the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enclosing the string you want with brackets, like so:

```
def printString():

    mystring = ('title\n'
                '{{\\usepackage}}\n'
                'text continues {param}').format(param='myParameter')

    return mystring
```

This would allow you to break the string to several lines while c=having control over the whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use brackets to maintain tidiness of long strings inside functions.

```
def printString():
    mystring = ("title\n"
    "{{\\usepackage}}\n"
    "text continues {param}"
    ).format(param='myParameter')

    return (mystring)

print(printString())
```

Results in:

```
title
{\usepackage}
text continues myParameter
```

You may also wish to explicitly use the `+` symbol to represent string concatenation, but that changes this from a compile time operation to a runtime operation. [Source](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation)

```
def printString():
    mystring = ("title\n" +
    "{{\\usepackage}}\n" +
    "text continues {param}"
    ).format(param='myParameter')

    return (mystring)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub` to cleanup any spaces and tabs at the beginning of each lines

```
>>> import re
>>> def printString():
...     mystring = '''title\n
...     {{\\usepackage}}\n
...     text continues {param}
...     '''.format(param='myParameter')
...
...     return re.sub(r'\n[ \t]+', '\n', mystring)
...
```

This gives the following o/p

```
>>> a = printString()
>>> print (a)
title

{\usepackage}

text continues myParameter
```